# How can I hide a user from the Welcome Screen?

Tags: greeter

I recently installed virt-manager. It created a user – Libvirt Qemu (libvirt-qemu) – and that user shows on the Welcome Screen.

I don't want that user to show up on the Welcome Screen. How can I hide it?

I've already tried the following:

- Added "libvirt-qemu" to the "hidden-users=" line in /etc/lightdm/users.conf
- Created /var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu with
  `[User]`
  `SystemAccount=true`

[image: User Accounts Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your second option worked for me, for what it's worth. At first I suspected that maybe the permissions needed to be `600` rather than `644`, but that didn't seem to matter.

In my case, it was `citrixlog`, a user created with user ID 1001 by the Citrix Workspace client for Linux.

```
# replace 'citrixlog' with whatever user pertains to your situation
echo '[User]
SystemAccount=true' | sudo tee /var/lib/AccountsService/users/citrixlog
```

Then, either reboot —or— log out of the graphical environment, switch to a virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and restart the following two services:

```
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

An alternative, mentioned in [this Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114303/how-to-limit-user-names-in-lightdm-login-screen-when-accountsservice-is-used/114321#114321) is to change the user ID to something less than 500, so it's considered a "system" account and hidden from the greeter.

One downside to that alternative is you may have to change the owner/group on all the files and directories belonging to that user, and that's beyond the scope of this thread. Besides, the user / group ID will probably go back to what it was before next time its associated package gets updated. So use the first method above, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same question and I don't really understand the purpose why that user appears. But I just simply deleted it from the user accounts (hit the "-" button in left bottom corner).
The user is totally deleted - however I checked if that doesn't impact my virtualization after that : everything is OK (I'm using VMware workstation and GNS3).
Stupidly I didn't check some other possibilities (such as checking login shell, cf. https://askubuntu.com/a/906997/1148936 or https://askubuntu.com/a/940069/1148936) - which seems to be the preferred way to get rid of that.